# Advanced indexing in Torch? (Is there a PyTorch equivalent of np.ix_?)

Tags: numpy, pytorch

In Numpy, I can index arrays using arbitrary combinations of boolean and numerical indices. E.g.

```
>>> x = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> x[np.ix_([False, True, True], [0, 3])] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  5,  6,  2],
       [ 3,  9, 10,  4]])
```

Suppose that `x` and the indexing arrays (both boolean and numerical) are all torch tensors (on the GPU, if that makes any difference). Is there a way to index and mutate `x` as in the Numpy solution?

Comment: If `torch` follows `numpy` in handling advanced indexing (`broadcasting` indexing arrays), then the `np.ix_` result should work on a tensor as well.  This is all Python.  The `ix_` is evaluated first, and result passed to the indexing function  (`x.__getitem__()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `np.ix_` does is convert boolean array inputs to arrays of integer indices (via `.nonzero`), and then introduces singleton dimensions to facilitate broadcasting. For instance:

```
x[ np.ix_(idx1, idx2, idx3) ]
```

is equivalent to

```
x[ idx1[:, None, None], idx2[None, :, None], idx3[None, None, :] ]
```

provided that each index contains integers.

I don't know of any `ix_` equivalent in pytorch, but coincidentally, after converting your boolean index with `.nonzero`, the resulting shape is already perfect for broadcasting:

```
>>> import torch
>>>
>>> x = torch.arange(12).reshape(3, 4).cuda()
>>>
>>> rows = torch.tensor([False, True, True]).cuda()
>>> cols = cols = torch.tensor([0, 3]).cuda()
>>> val = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).cuda()
>>>
>>> x[rows.nonzero(), cols] = val
>>> x
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  5,  6,  2],
        [ 3,  9, 10,  4]], device='cuda:0')
```

in a more general context however you could insert singleton dimensions for broadcasting into your index tensors similar to how `np.ix_` does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`torch.meshgrid`](https://torch.meshgrid):

```
>>> x = torch.arange(12).view(3, 4)

>>> x[torch.meshgrid(torch.tensor([1,2]), torch.tensor([0,3]))]
tensor([[ 4,  7],
        [ 8, 11]])
```

Comment: In `numpy`, `np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[4,5],sparse=True, indexing='ij')` produces the same as `np.ix_([1,2,3],[4,5])` - except one is a list, and other a tuple.